# Merging of Android Manifests

Tags: android, parse-platform, merge, android-manifest

I am trying to merge two simple android manifests but I have a debug error such as :

AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method with name='setApplicationPaused' signature='(Z)V' in class Lcom/parse/ParsePushUnityHelper;

I guess one of the plugin has a wrong reference

I have merger this android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.unity3d.player" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="com.prime31.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

And this android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="life.belt.gb3d"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="life.belt.gb3d.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="life.belt.gb3d.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

  <application android:label="ParseUnityPushSample" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon">
    <activity android:name=".UnityPlayerActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="life.belt.gb3d" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.parse.ParsePushService" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

To this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.unity3d.player" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="life.belt.gb3d.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="life.belt.gb3d.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="com.prime31.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="life.belt.gb3d" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.parse.ParsePushService" />

  </application>
</manifest>
```

Can someone tell me what went wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have changed your manifest package to `com.unity3d.player`. I believe which is the Unity library. Now your application is starting from there but `Parse` dependency is only available in your app module (whose package id is `life.belt.gb3d`).

So try to change your package back to `life.belt.gb3d` and modify your manifest like this,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="life.belt.gb3d"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    ....
    <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true"
        tools:merge="override">
    ....
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: With such change, some function from the first plugin stopped working with such problems : "Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzh" also the first problem "AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method with name='setApplicationPaused' signature='(Z)V' in class Lcom/parse/ParsePushUnityHelper;" I think instead of changing com.unity3d.player, I need to change life.belt.gb3d in a way. Can you suggest what I can do more please? Manifests are new to me